# SparkSQL dataframe retain partitioning columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Lets assume that I have a JSON file, lets name it foo, with the following contents:
{"a": 2, "b": 3}

My goal is to write partitioned data based on the "a" column.

Then from my code I do something like this:

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json("foo");
df.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("a").json("output");
```

Everything is fine and I get the following structure at the output:

```
output
 |
 |-->a=2
      |-> part-blahblah
```

When I inspect the contents of part-blahblah then the "a" field is missing from the contents.

My question is if there is any way to control this behavior (through options or code) in order to retain the partitioning column (so the created file will contain both a and b instead of only b). The reason for this is that I want to load data from other applications that are not partition-aware and they cannot infer the partitioning scheme.  I thought of copying the field a to "_a" and partition by "_a" but it is not elegant and creates problems.

Thanks!

Comment: "The reason for this is that I want to load data from other applications that are not partition-aware and they cannot infer the partitioning scheme" But the partitioning scheme can be inferred form the directory structure/names by the other application? I don't think there is another way (other than duplicating your column using another name)

Comment: unfortunately it cannot. in some cases I load directories recursively and load objects so the directory structure is not present.

Answer (score 2):

You should duplicate the column that you are partitioning by.

In PySpark

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn("a_partition", F.col("a"))
df.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("a_partition").json("output");
```